# DoCapture API returns ACK => Success but PAYMENTSTATUS => Pending and PENDINGREASON is paymentreview

Tags: woocommerce, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am authorizing payment through a wordpress website[woocommerce - 2.4.12]. After that I am using "DoCapture Api" for Capture Authorized payment to automate the system.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoCapture_API_Operation_NVP/

I am using below code in wordpress/woocommerce[2.4.12]

```
function get_capture_request( $order, $amount = null ) {
    $request = array(
        'VERSION'         => '84.0',
        'SIGNATURE'       => 'SIGNATURE',
        'USER'            => 'USER',
        'PWD'             => 'PWD',
        'METHOD'          => 'DoCapture',
        'AUTHORIZATIONID' => get_post_meta($order->id, '_transaction_id', true ),
        'AMT'             => number_format( is_null( $amount ) ? $order->get_total() : $amount, 2, '.', '' ),
        'CURRENCYCODE'    => 'CAD',
        'COMPLETETYPE'    => 'Complete',
    );
    return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_paypal_capture_request', $request, $order, $amount );
}

$sandbox = 'https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp';
$raw_response = wp_safe_remote_post($sandbox,
    array(
        'method'      => 'POST',
        'body'        => get_capture_request( $order, $amount ),
        'timeout'     => 70,
        'user-agent'  => 'WooCommerce/' . WC()->version,
        'httpversion' => '1.1',
    )
);
```

In response I am getting below response.

```
stdClass Object
(
    [AUTHORIZATIONID] => AUTHORIZATIONID
    [TIMESTAMP] => 2019-09-15T08:52:50Z
    [CORRELATIONID] => CORRELATIONID
    [ACK] => Success
    [VERSION] => 84.0
    [BUILD] => 53497452
    [TRANSACTIONID] => TRANSACTIONID
    [PARENTTRANSACTIONID] => PARENTTRANSACTIONID
    [PAYMENTTYPE] => instant
    [ORDERTIME] => 2019-09-15T08:52:48Z
    [AMT] => 6.24
    [FEEAMT] => 0.48
    [CURRENCYCODE] => CAD
    [PAYMENTSTATUS] => Pending
    [PENDINGREASON] => paymentreview
    [REASONCODE] => None
    [SHIPPINGMETHOD] => Default
    [PROTECTIONELIGIBILITY] => Ineligible
    [PROTECTIONELIGIBILITYTYPE] => None
)
```

but I don't know why I am getting PAYMENTSTATUS Pending and also in pending reason there is no "paymentreview" option[ https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoCapture-API-Operation-NVP/ ].

Can any one guide me what is the problem here?

Thank in advance.

Comment: When you go to merchant view on PayPal, the status of the order is Pending or Completed?